# DateTime() method does not work when i display a BETWEEN clause - Mysql/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, function, variables

I have a PHP function that executes a MySQL query with a few variables defined. I need the `BETWEEN` clause of the SQL statement to work with the variables, where one of the variables is the `DateTime()` function.

Here the `$start` variable should be making a new time and then the value I have in my database should be between this time and the `$finish` variable i have defined.

```
$start = new DateTime();

$finish = '2013-10-06 17:06:52';

$value = $this->GetOffset();

$this->db->select("esolar + $value AS Esolar", 1)
     ->from('calcdata')
     ->where('siteid', $siteid)
     ->where("time BETWEEN '$start' AND '$finish'")     
     ->where('esolar <', 1000000)
     ->where('esolar <>', 0);
$query1 = $this->db->get()->result_array();
$Esolar1 = $query1[0]['Esolar'];
```

However when I do it I get this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 4096
> Message: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do something like:

```
$start = $start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

otherwise you will pass an object instead of a string as a parameter

Answer (score 2):

your `$start` is of DateTime class - you need to convert it to string ...

This can be done using the `format` method -> `$start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Answer (score 1):

This is because to convert the DateTime object to the string form you have to use it's [format()](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.format.php) method. In your case it will become something like this:

```
$this->db->select("esolar + $value AS Esolar", 1)
 ->from('calcdata')
 ->where('siteid', $siteid)
 ->where("time BETWEEN '".$start->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' AND '".$finish->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")."'")     
 ->where('esolar <', 1000000)
 ->where('esolar <>', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see `$start` is not initialized to any value, so it contains current date/time.
Given this you could change query with

```
...
time BETWEEN NOW() AND '$finish'")
...
```

without having to use `DateTime` object

Comment: The default when a new DateTime object is constructed is to construct it with the current date / time - like the NOW() suggestion though :-)

Comment: @ManseUK: my edited post should reflect your suggestion. Thanks :)